# Furnace: are flames in between the tubes bad?

Tags: furnace, natural-gas

In a Carrier Weathermaker 8000 gas furnace, is it normal for some of the flames to be coming out of the spacers in between the tubes? It seems like they shouldn't be there, since they aren't going through the holes into the box with the blower.
[image: drawing of the flames in a Carrier furnace]
(Please pardon any inaccuracy in my terminology.)

Comment: Take a look and listen to this video but it sounds like this thing should have  sensors in it that will detect faulty heat exchanger, incorrect flame throwout, etc. but it'd be best to have a professional take a look at if you feel it's not normal as carbon monoxide can be deadly so I wouldn't guess at it regardless if you feel something is not right: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtMgwOwncIQ. . . I suggest getting someone to look at it for you that is physically there to see, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably normal operation.

There is a flash tube for lighting all the burners after the ignitor lights the first one.  A small amount of flame out of that tube during furnace operation is normal.  If excessive flame escapes from the burner tubes, a device called a "roll out sensor" will shut the furnace down.